# 401 Unauthorized response only on new version of chrome/firefox browsers when using the WP-API Basic-Auth plugin

Tags: wordpress, basic-authentication, wordpress-rest-api, wp-api

I have installed the plugin made by the Wordpress Team: https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth

I am making this request with Wordpress 4.6.14:

The making a GET request to the following API 
https://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?access_token=blnhszockfpzflz9v7nu312s

To get the user data from WordPress but it's giving me 401 status on new versions of Chrome and Firefox browsers.

I tried this API call using postman and it's working fine.

When I use an older version of Firefox it gives me 302 status.

I have tried all the solutions that are mentioned in "401 Unauthorized with Wordpress Basic Auth Plugin" question plus all solutions mentioned in https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth/issues but still no luck. Please, can anyone help me with this?

Please refer to the following screenshot of my network tab
[image]

Comment: If you look into the network tab of your debugger, do you see the credentials properly attached to the request?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have updated the question with the screenshot of my network tab

Comment: Could you show the code you use to mak the above request? Some libraries need certain flags to enable automatic authorization headers

Comment: This is the code I'm using to make the request. 
`fetch('/web/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?access_token='+ token.access_token)
 .then((response) => {console.log(response)})` I tried with axios library still the same outcome